# jquery unexpected token

Tags: jquery

I'm having some trouble with my jquery script as it keeps having trouble with an

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

```
$("#hm_01").mouseover(function(){
    $(.hover_top).delay(700).css(opacity: 1;-webkit-transform:translate(-10px,-10px));
    $(.hover_top).css(opacity: 1;animation: hover 0.7s;-webkit-animation: hover 0.7s);
    $(.hover_bottom).delay(700).css(opacity:1); 
    $(.hover_bottom).css(animation:reveal 1s;-webkit-animation: reveal 1s);
});
```

Additionally, I was wondering whether or not it would be possible that I can call a jquery script by function name. For instance, my div has a *onmouseover="script()"* and my *script()* is defined like

```
function hm_01(){
    $(.hover_top).delay(700).css(
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform:translate(-10px,-10px);
    );
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$(.hover_top)` and `.css(opacity: 1;-webkit-transform:translate(-10px,-10px))` is invalid JavaScript. Have a look at the documentation for examples:http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/, http://api.jquery.com/css/. The MDN JavaScript Guide might also be helpful to learn the basic JS syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: I think `$(.hover_top)` should be `$(".hover_top")` (ect ect) Acutally you're missing string delimiters everywhere...

Comment: @asawyer: OP probably have their quote key on the keyboard broken :-S

Comment: [QUOTATION MARKS, QUOTATION MARKS, QUOTATION MARKS, QUOTATION MARKS](http://justanothermobilemonday.com/Wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/steveballmersweatingjpg.jpeg) `:P`

Answer (score 2):

You need to put quotes around your selector expression i.e. $(".hover_top") not $(.hover_top).

Also you need to review how the .css() function is used in jQuery - http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Selector *expressions*, not statements.